# Adding a link using xacro

Tags: ros, gazebo, joint, urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For a model to show in gazebo, I'm using several xacro files written by someone who is no longer available. I need to add a link (camera) to an existing link by means of a fixed joint so I modified the xacro that contains the existing link and added a fixed joint and a camera link.
I've tried this before using only urdf, parsing it, and showing in gazebo. This worked great and the camera gives a nice view.
With this xacro however, no matter what I try, it parses fine but the link doesn't show up in gazebo and the link also isn't available when checking rostopic list.

So my question is: assuming that the xacro can be modified and parsed this way, what more should I do to get the new link showing in Gazebo and in rostopic list.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63143/adding-a-link-using-xacro/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're combining a few too many steps. Xacro is only a means to getting a URDF. Can you run xacro outside of your launch file and see if it matches the URDF that works in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1